# Error: $.ajax is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Am getting a error like that, $ajax is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnsubmit").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "loginform.aspx/getdataval",
      data: "{'uname':'" + $("#TextBox1").val() + "','passwod':'" + $("#TextBox2").val() + "'}",
      contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (msg) {
        alert("welcome");
        AjaxSucceeded(msg);
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("what is the problem")
      }

    });
  });
});

function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
  alert(result.d);
  var Emp = result.d;
  $("#output").append('<p>' + Emp.Sname + ' ' + Emp.Sno + '</p>');
}
</script>
```

$ ajax not a function why? When I run this script I get error, it not running, what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you importing an other library which overwrites `$`, after the ready callback was executed? You might be able to solve the issue you defining the callback as `$(document).ready(function ($) {...})` (i.e. make it accept a reference to jQuery).

Comment: no, no any other library

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/ZmYqh/

Comment: Is your entire code available somewhere ? There could be a typo like `$.ajax=`, `$.ajax:` or something else.

Comment: What's the version of the imported jquery ?

Comment: but wher is the success message

Comment: check ur doc type and aspx heddr file

Comment: pls mention the exact error msg you are getting. *$ajax is not working* or *$ajax not a function* ?

Comment: If you don't provide more information, we cannot help you. The code you posted as is does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have an issue with the single/doule quotes on the data string as the JSON standard says double quotes.
You can also simplify the contentType.
I tend to simplify my use of the .d in asp.net by including a converter and the ajax itself using ajaxSetup like so:  (Note that using a converter like this works in jQuery 1.5 forward due to that syntax.  Feel free to refactor out the ajaxSetup if you prefer but I find it helps me as I only have to do it once when I have multiple ajax calls.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        converters: {
            "json jsond": function(msg) {
                return msg.hasOwnProperty('d') ? msg.d : msg;
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var errorMessage = "Ajax error: " + this.url
                 + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown 
                 + " : " + xhr.statusText + " : " + xhr.status;
            alert(errorMessage);
            if (xhr.status != "0" || errorThrown != "abort") {
                alert(errorMessage);
            }
        }
    });
    $("#btnsubmit").click(function() {
        var pString = '{"uname":"' 
             + $("#TextBox1").val() + '","passwod":"' 
             + $("#TextBox2").val() + '"}';
        $.ajax({
            url: "loginform.aspx/getdataval",
            data: pString,
            success: function(msg) {
                alert("welcome");
                AjaxSucceeded(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});

// converter gives us the result instead of the .d here
function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
    alert(result);
    var Emp = result;
    $("#output").append('<p>' + Emp.Sname + ' ' + Emp.Sno + '</p>');
}
```

EDIT: as of jQuery 1.9, you should bind the ajax setup as such:

```
 $(document).ajaxSetup({..more code
```